# scrollView.requestFocus() returns true, but it not works

Tags: android, android-layout

All,I hava a scroll contains a editText.

Once I clicks the editText ,it gets focus and a SoftInput shows.

In my mind, if I clicks the blank space , the softinput hide, and editText lose the focus, and scrollview get focus.

So my code like this:

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //call twice, once down, once up
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null && activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() != null) {
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    scrollView.requestFocus();
                    activity.getCurrentFocus();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });



ScrollView
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

But after all, editText still focus(activity.getCurrentFocus() == editText), any advices?

Comment: remove focus from edit text programatically.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I use 'activity.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();', still nothing happened

Answer (score -1):

Use LinearLayout instead of ScrollView. Or wrap EditText with LinearLayout below.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Could you specify what is your problem? How did your code behave and what did you expected?